# C# core HTML5 video won't load in chrome with range tags

Tags: c#, .net-core, html5-video

We are currently working on a simple HTML page that loads a video via HTML5 tag.  On the backend we have a webapi endpoint that returns a video (or chunk of video) with the "Accept-Ranges: bytes" header.

Chrome seems to make two calls to the endpoint, one with bytes:0- and one with bytes:10452992-

The video is MP4 and 10498677 bytes long.

The video, however, does not play and just loads as a black screen.

Our endpoint looks like this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> StreamVideoWithToken(string token, long id)
```

To get the start byte location we use:

```
var range = Request.Headers["Range"].First();
var rangeType = range.Split('=');
if (rangeType[0] == "bytes")
{
    var firstLast = rangeType[1].Split('-');
    long first = 0;
    if (firstLast.Length > 0 && firstLast[0] != "")
        if (!long.TryParse(firstLast[0], out first)) first = 0;

    long last = 0;
    if (firstLast.Length > 1)
        if (!long.TryParse(firstLast[1], out last)) last = 0;

    byteRange.start = first;
    byteRange.end = last;
}
```

This gets the start byte.

We then get the stream from the server and pass it back as a response.

```
// Returns a stream of only the required bytes (start to EOF)
var fs = _assetService.GetContentStream(asset.Id, byteRange.start);

fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Response.ContentLength = byteRange.start + s.fetchedLength;

if (byteRange.start > 0)
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", byteRange.start + "-" + (byteRange.start + s.fetchedLength));
}

return new FileStreamResult(fs, "video/mp4")~;
```

If we turn off the "Accept-Ranges: bytes" header, it does a single request with the full video, which plays successfully, but can't be navigated to any specific time.

The request looks like this:

```
GET: https://localhost:44392/api/asset/StreamVideo/xxx/1261

Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Range: bytes=10452992-
Referer: http://localhost:4200/catalogue/a/1261
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
```

The response looks like this:

```
Status Code: 206 (Partial Content)

accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Content-Type, x-auth-token
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: X-Error-Message
content-length: 45685
content-range: 10452992-10498677
content-type: video/mp4
date: Sun, 22 Sep 2019 14:49:14 GMT
server: Kestrel
status: 206
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
x-sourcefiles: xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your implementation (and please post full code, with these snippets it is not possible to understand what is `s` when you are using `s.Item2`):

1. `fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` - either this is a typo or you haven't understood how the range header works. You must seek to the offset specified as the start of the range and serve only up to the end of the range.
2. When handling the range values you currently leave `last` as 0 if it is not provided, but remember that in that case you still need to serve the contents from the start to the end of the file.
3. To play nice you should also set the [Content-Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range) header on the response, since you are replying with 206.

**Edit:**
If you use [FileResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) instead of `FileStreamResult`it will take care of the `Range` header itself, just be aware that the behavior changes in 2.1 - below 2.1 the class does the processing automatically, since 2.1 you need to enable `EnableRangeProcessing` property of `FileResult` for the processing to happen.

Comment: 1.fs.seek -  I only retrieve the portion of the file that I want to return, so I have to start at the beginning of the stream (so, if they start at byte 9000 of a 10000 file, my stream is only 1000 bytes long)

2. if last is 0 (actually, if last is anything), I always return from start  to end

3. I added the content-range header, but no difference.  See edits above for changed response.

Comment: I also renamed s.Item2 - to s.fetchedLength   - this is the length of the content retrieved (so 1000 bytes if they ask for range 9000-end)

Comment: "I only retrieve the portion of the file that I want to return" - where in the code that you have posted is that visible? You simply seek to the first byte.

Comment: Added the line of code that returns the portion of the file that is requested from the server (these aren't files on a drive, but contained in an asset manager, so we can retrieve partial content.  GetContentStream(asset.Id, byteRange.start); returns from "requested start" to EOF

Comment: @TrevorWatson, ok, now at least the `Seek` makes sense. The only other thing that seems weird is that your content-length is one off to the range - your range is 10452992-10498677, so the content length should be 10498677-10452992+1=45686‬. Also, maybe format the header as per this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range: `<start>-<end>/<size>`.  If none of this helps then well paste us a working URL to this system so we can test it with ffmpeg or smth similar.